# How can php change label html value?

Tags: php

In asp.net, I can have server controls like Textbox and etc.

Does PHP have web server control like asp.net?

I want to change a label html value.

Comment: Provide example of what you want to achieve.

Comment: PHP code base doesn't provide snippets of HTML like the monstrosity of ASP.NET. You'll need to change `<label></label>` or `<input placeholder="" />` to edit your "label".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there was no provided example you wanted help with here is a small snippet of how it would work.

```
 $user = "StackO";    
 <input type="text" placeholder="Example" name="custom" value="<?php echo $user; ?>">
```

This would put `StackO` as the value of the textbox. The `value` is the `text` of the textbox it's self.

Answer (score 4):

According to my knowledge PHP Use HTML. Ex Think You Want to Show Something On a Lable

```
<?php $value1 = "Hello World"; ?>
<label><?php echo $value1; ?></label>
```

According to me PHP is simple (You Don't have to worry about CS file and Aspx File like in Asp.net Just Write your code Inline.)